# IMAP IDLE does not seem to work with iCloud email and S22.IMAP

Tags: email, imap, icloud

I was implementing the example shown [here](http://smiley22.github.io/S22.Imap/Documentation/html/E_S22_Imap_ImapClient_NewMessage.htm) using S22.IMAP specifically the NewMessage event.

I was sending test emails from my Gmail account to my iCloud and the event was not firing.  I reversed them and sent to my Gmail and the event was fired.  Does iCloud not actually support IMAP IDLE? It did not throw the exception saying it did not or is there some special thing you have to do to get iCloud to push to your application?

```
    public EmailInstance(String email, SupportedMailTypes type)
    {
        _emailAddress = email;
        _mailType = type;
        InitializeEmail();
    }

    private void InitializeEmail()
    {
        if (_mailType == SupportedMailTypes.Gmail)
        {
            _client = new ImapClient(GMAIL_SERVER, PORT, _emailAddress, PASSWORD, AuthMethod.Login, true);                          
        }
        else if (_mailType == SupportedMailTypes.iCloud)
        {
            _client = new ImapClient(ICLOUD_SERVER, PORT, _emailAddress, PASSWORD, AuthMethod.Login, true);
        }

        // Download mail messages from the default mailbox.
        NewEmailCount = GetMessageCount();

        // Check that IDLE is supported by the server
        if (_client.Supports("IDLE") == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Server does not support IDLE.");
        }

        _client.IdleError += OnIdleError;
        _client.NewMessage += OnNewMessage;
        _client.MessageDeleted += OnMessageDeleted;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If idling throws an error.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnIdleError(object sender, IdleErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Exception.Message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// What to do when the client receives a new message.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnNewMessage(object sender, IdleMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        NewEmailCount = GetMessageCount(); 
        var header = _client.GetMessage(e.MessageUID, FetchOptions.HeadersOnly, false);
    }

    private void OnMessageDeleted(object sender, IdleMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        NewEmailCount = GetMessageCount();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the message count
    /// </summary>
    private int GetMessageCount()
    {
        var uids = _client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());                    
        return _client.GetMessages(uids, FetchOptions.HeadersOnly, false).Count();
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement the part of the example that says if(!Client.Supports("IDLE")) ...?

Comment: @arnt I did.  This is what is confusing me.  It's not erroring out, and the event is not being called like when Gmail receives it.  Gmail works, iCloud didn't.

Comment: IIRC, icloud is based on dovecot, an open source thing that supports idle, so they must've actively removed it. I suggest testing whether it's the server or your client using openssl s_client -connect foo:993 -crlf, then a login dustin asdfasdf, then b select inbox, then c idle. Read mail or delete some using any client, and you should see lines appear in the openssl session informing you of the changes.

Comment: @arnt I'll do that tonight and post the results. Cheers.

Comment: iCloud supports IDLE.

Comment: @arnt Ok so I tried out the openssl s_client and indeed the command prompt received the events when i deleted mail.  Now I suppose the question is why the code C# code I wrote it not receiving it.

Comment: @arnt So this is the code I've implemented.  The gmail account has no problem idling and updating the UI, but iCloud will only update when I load the program.  Thus, IdleError, NewMessage, and MessageDeleted events never actually fire for iCloud.